# How to get the last inserted id using scope identity without using a stored procedure in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

My project contains  2 tables one is profile_table and another is address_table

Profile_ table contains:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| sid  | sname   | saddress |
+------+---------+----------+
|  1   | xyz     |   india  |
|  2   | abc     |     U.S  |
+------+---------+----------+
```

‘sid’ field in profile_table is made as primary key and autoincremented field.

The address table also  contains 'sid':

```
+------+---------+----------+-------
| sid  | squalification    | smarks |
+------+---------+----------+-------
|  1   |    B.E            | 80     |
|  2   |    M.S            |  85    |
+------+------------------ +--------+
```

The sid column in 'address_table' is made as foreign key in the address table and when I inserted the first record in the profile_table that sid value must be inserted in the   address_table along with squalification,smarks values.I want to use 'last inserted id' concept here and i dont want to use the stored procedure. please explain me how to get the last inserted id using scope identity without using a stored procedure in Mysql.

Answer (score 2):

The [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function will return what you are looking for. It is a built-in function, does that qualify?

I'm not sure what you mean by excluding "stored procedure"; maybe it's just wrong terminology and you wish to also exclude built-in functions?